# I just upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04. Now my DCM4313 wireless card isn't working. Help?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, upgrade

I've tried everything I can think of and used all the official documentation to try to fix it but nothing is working. What gives? Would a clean install work? Anyone have a suggestion? PS. I'm not that computer savvy, please explain like I'm five.

Answer (score 1):

I just got a issue similar like you. Like, I, whenever installs ubuntu from "inside the windows" using wubi, I could not connect to wireless and had no configuration for it at all. I figured out that my driver could not be found for wireless. Now when I installed ubuntu from outside the windows and made windows partition a secondary one, I got it correct automatically. I just used 'iwconfig` to test out if the configuration is automatically set and yes it was. So i will recommend you to get a fresh install of ubuntu from outside the windows operating system

Comment: I don't have a windows partition.

Comment: maybe there is some problem with the wireless driver package.did u tried installing threw additional drivers or manually?

Comment: Yup. The install keeps failing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager.
2. Uninstall `bcmwl-kernel-source` package.
3. Reboot.

This should cure the problem. :-)

Comment: You are a life saver. You deserve an award. Thank you!!!

Comment: please mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you could try a fresh install. If you pop in a live cd (cd with 12.04 burned on it) try and see if you can connect to wifi on the disk boot before making the decision to installing it. Note fresh install will delete everything, so backup anything you want to keep.

Comment: If it works don't forget to check the answer that helped.

Comment: Unfortunatly, the CD doesn't seem to be working. I keep trying to boot from the CD and it just doesn't work - it keeps going straight to boot from my hard drive. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: you have to change the settings in you BIOS to boot from CD. Google how to boot your specific computer into BIOS then put CD at the top level above hard drive.

Comment: I know how to boot from a CD...it's just not working correctly.

Comment: Maybe it's a bad disk. you might have to burn another disk

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with my wireless as well - my issue specifically was that it kept dropping and reconnecting frequently. if this is what you're experiencing, just switch your wifi router to channel 1 (or any other channel except 6 or 11). you should be solid then.

Comment: I don't know what this means..

Answer (score 0):

[Dell Upgrade to 13.04 & 13.10 No wifi, graphic card driver and bluetooth Problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130477/dell-upgrade-to-12-04-lts-no-wifi-and-bluetooth-problem) This may help

By Using the command :

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This worked to re-instill the wifi drivers now my wifi is working.

[image]