# Dell Upgrade to 13.04 & 13.10 No wifi, graphic card driver and bluetooth Problem?

Tags: wireless, upgrade, dell, bluetooth, 13.04

### (Dell inspiron m5040 Upgrade to 12.04 LTS from 11.10 wifi wont work and has two bluetooth icons?) Old title of post!

**No Wifi/Bluetooth Problem. "Both Fixed", see below comments for bluetooth fix and see bottom answer for wifi fix.**

My online upgrade of 13.04, was installed to my laptop the Dell inspiron m5040, when it was done i found that my wifi did not even get picked up anymore and i now have two bluetooth icons at the top??

[image]

So what i have been doing for now is at the boot screen. I hit the use previous linux version, this works fine but also has the two bluetooth at the top.

[image]

***Is very thankful for any answers for this fix, Thank You.***

Ok bluetooth problem solved by – [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) answer by deleting the other bluetooth program running in software center.

Now the other problem is Wifi:
just have to restart system as it works in previous linux version boot opt, but on the first boot screen opt run ubuntu it will not pick up wifi drivers.

Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driverfor use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-,BCM4322-, BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-basedhardware.

And

3D-accelerated proprietary graphics driver for ATI cards.

This driver is required to fully utilise the 3D potential of some ATI graphics cards, as well as provide 2D acceleration of newer cards.

will not instill is there anyway for me to make a copy of the drivers via usb HDD and then put them on new upgraded version.

[image]

Comment: have you got both bluetooth and blueman installed?  - search for "bluetooth" in software center.

Comment: Il have a look its weird, the other thing my wifi wont work, etc

Comment: as to your wifi - we need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: oki just going to update the info on wifi problem.

Comment: this question started off discussing bluetooth and wifi and now has morphed into graphics!  Please ask your graphics question as a separate question.  Plug your laptop using the wired connection.  Then activate the STA driver in the Additional Drivers window.  What happens after a reboot?

Comment: Ok will do and sorry about putting in about the graphics but all looks to me around the same problem, that the Additional Drivers wont install. Anyway ill check back in tomorrow and give you an update on the fix, etc. Thanks for the information, that you have given so far worked a teat, thanks.

Comment: Fixed by Answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Wifi/Graphic Driver Fix**

---

In the end i found the problem was fixed by seeing the post 
[Dell Inspiron 1525, Upgraded to 12.04 and have lost Wireless Internet Connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125624/dell-inspiron-1525-upgraded-to-12-04-and-have-lost-wireless-internet-connection)

I used the commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

*Or use `purge` instead of `remove` to wipe it, then re-install.*

This worked to re-install the wifi drivers now my wifi is working.

I wondered if maybe this would also work for the graphics driver for my ATI/AMD cards.
So I tried to re-install the graphics drivers and this also worked.

The commands for the graphics fix were:

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

*Or use `purge` instead of `remove` to wipe it, then re-install.*

And a big thanks to [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) For solving the Bluetooth matter.

[image: GUI window showing activated Broadcom proprietary wireless driver]

As you can see, now all seems to be working.