# Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Inspiron n5010 Laptop. I can't install the ATI drivers!

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, dell, inspiron

After a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Inspiron n5010 Laptop, I can't install the ATI drivers! How I can fix this? Because my laptop gets very hot & is too slow! the battery runs immediately! :( Gretts!

Comment: How you try to install it? Did you run "additional driver" application? Please post details here.

Answer (score 1):

From: [Dell Upgrade to 13.04 & 13.10 No wifi, graphic card driver and bluetooth Problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130477/dell-upgrade-to-12-04-lts-no-wifi-and-bluetooth-problem/132693#132693)

**Wifi/Graphics Driver Fix**

---

I used the commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This worked to re-install the wifi drivers and now my wifi is working.

I was thinking maybe this will work for the graphics driver for ATI/AMD cards.

So I tried to re-install the graphics drivers and it worked.

Command for graphics fix was:

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

[image: Driver is activated and currently in use]

As you can see, now all seems to be working.

Answer (score -1):

Dell Inspirion N-5050

Ddownload two .deb packages: [dkms](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/dkms/download) and [bcmwl-kernel-source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/bcmwl-kernel-source/download).

Install it! It is works!

**Edit**: the easiest way to install these packages is using apt. Open a terminal (Alt + Ctrl + T) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: Either you download the .deb file and install it with "sudo dpkg -i <the-deb-file>" **or** you just issue the "apt-get"-command which will try to download it by itself and install it.